# Is it mandatory for backtracking algorithm to start from back?

Tags: algorithm, backtracking

I solved the wordbreakII problem [here](https://oj.leetcode.com/problems/word-break-ii/) by the backtracking algorithm.
Following is the code:

```
public static List<String> wordBreak(String s, Set<String> dict) {
    List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
    int len = s.length();
    for (int i = len -1; i >= 0; i--) {
        String last = s.substring(i, len);  //get the last word and process the rest
        if (dict.contains(last)) {
            if (i == 0) {
                words.add(last);
            } else {
                String remain = s.substring(0, i);
                List<String> remainSet = wordBreak(remain, dict);
                if (remainSet != null) {
                    for (String item : remainSet) {
                        words.add(item + " " + last);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return words;
}
```

If I try to process from the front, the result should be same.

```
public static List<String> wordBreakFront(String s, Set<String> dict) {
    List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

    int len = s.length();
    for (int i = 1; i <= len; i++) {
        String front = s.substring(0, i);
        if (dict.contains(front)) {
            if (i == len) {
                words.add(front);
            } else {
                //get the front word and process the rest.  
                String remain = s.substring(i, len);
                List<String> remainSet = wordBreak(remain, dict);
                if (remainSet != null) {
                    for (String item : remainSet) {
                        words.add(front + " " + item);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return words;
}
```

The front-tracking also works(can generate correct output). But it comes with a low efficiency, then it failed in the time limit test. The later failed on this case:

//Last executed input:  "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaab", ["a","aa","aaa","aaaa","aaaaa","aaaaaa","aaaaaaa","aaaaaaaa","aaaaaaaaa","aaaaaaaaaa"]

So I don't understand why start from the back will make difference?

Thanks.

Comment: This seems like you only solved finding possible **words**.  That example says find all possible **sentences**.  Like how it shows finding "cats and dog" or "cat sand dog"  So my point being if someone said backtracking is important here its possible that it is because you didn't solve the real problem.

Comment: A `backtracking` algorithm is not one which starts at the back of anything, it is an algorithm which proceeds through a (conceptual) search space and upon encountering a blind alley (or one solution of expected many solutions or similar condition) `backtracks` along the path it has beaten through the search space until it comes to a (conceptual) junction from which it then takes another (conceptual) forward path.  Imagine yourself applying a blind algorithm to searching for the way out of a maze -- when you come to a dead end you `backtrack` to the last junction and take the other way.

Comment: @Carter, my solution find all the possible sentences. The first solution is submitted and accepted. The later one is actually the same but failed in one case. Please note "words" is an Arraylist which holds all the possible sentences.

Comment: @High Performance Mark Thanks for the clarification of the backtracking algorithm. Here do you think I am using backtracking? I think I am. For a string "catsanddog", we can move on with each letters, e.g. start with "c", if "c" is in dictionary, parsing the rest, if rest is parsed, combine with c+rest. if not, return and continue with "ca". This is same with finding way in a maze.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of them have exponential time complexity in the worst case. It is a matter of luck that the first one passed and the second one failed(if you reverse the input word and all words in the dictionary, the first one will work too long).

Comment: Yes, just found this...I also tried the reversed string. Thanks. So the algorithm back-tracking is just a name, it doesn't mean it should start from the back, does it?

Comment: @Jimmy You can start anywhere.